# Create a form_for in one view that posts to a controller for another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, form-for

I think this is pretty simple, but can't find an explanation anywhere on how to do it.

I have a profile page that has a form that when submitted should go though the `CompletedSetsController`but I can't figure out how to tell the form_for that I want to create/update via the already written `CompletedSetsController`, instead of rewriting the CRUD for `CompletedSets` in the ProfilesController

My `CompletedSetsController` is the scaffold generated CRUD controller.

Here is my form:

Right now, this form only works if I put `@completed_set = CompletedSet.new` in the `ProfileController`, but that's not very DRY, especially if I have to rewrite the create and update methods in the ProfilesController.

```
<%= form_for(@completed_set) do |f| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= we.exercise.name %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :exercise_id, :value => we.exercise.id %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :program_id, :value => @user_program.id %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => @user_group.id %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :workout_id, :value => @workout.id %>
            </td>
            <td><%= we.set %></td>
            <td><%= f.number_field :repetitions, :value => we.repetitions %></td>
            <td><%= if we.exercise.try(:is_cardio) == false then f.text_field :weight end %></td> <!-- :value => value of previous time user did this exercise -->
            <td><%= if we.rest.to_i >= 60 then  pluralize(we.rest.to_f / 60, 'minute') else pluralize(we.rest.to_i, 'second') end %></td>
            <td><%= if we.exercise.try(:is_cardio) == true then pluralize(we.time, 'minute') end %></td>
            <!-- <td><%#= if we.exercise.try(:is_cardio) == true then f.number_field :rpe, :value => we.rpe end %></td> Forgot to put this in table --> 
            <td><%= link_to 'Remove', workout_workout_exercise_path(@workout, we), method: :delete %></td>
            <td><%= f.submit %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
```

EDIT:

To be a bit more specific, my profile page is a [semi-static](http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages) page in the `UsersController` my UsersController is very basic:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def profile
      # @completed_set = CompletedSet.new
  end

  def settings
  end

end
```

All my controller logic is in the `CompletedSetsController` which I'm trying to avoid copying over into the UsersController

Comment: *ruby rails form for* on Google, first result: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for ...

Comment: Thanks for sharing your google results with me, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Create a form_for in one view **that posts to a controller for another view** and my "google result" tells you `<%= form_for @post, :as => :post, :url => posts_path ...` if just take the time to scroll down and read it and see the url attribute

Comment: I guess what I was trying to say is that I don't understand those answers, and how to use that information to answer my question.

Comment: I think your question's title is misleading. If the controller logic is exactly the same then just add another route, like `get "users/profile", to: "completed_sets#new"` (or nest that under your user routes)

Comment: Sorry. I have trouble coming up with good titles. This all works, but what I'm trying to do is have it update a record if the record exists, and create a record if it doesn't. Right now it just creates a new record every time I submit information instead of overwriting a record when one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a `url` option in `form_for` which will decide where the form submits to:

```
<%= form_for @completed_set, url: completed_sets_path do |f| %>
```

Comment: I'm still getting a "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" error when I do this.

Comment: Add your `new` and `create` action to the question.

Comment: Oh, and the title of the error page is "NoMethodError in Users#profile" so it's still looking in the wrong controller for the @completed_set. I'll update the question

Comment: This is the best answer. It's just missing the :as => :completed_set, so it should be <%= form_for(@completed_set, :as => :completed_set, :url => completed_sets_path) do |f| %>

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the available options on FormHelper, especially those for [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for). You can specify any url you want, should the default not be good for your case.